# How can we read random number of lines data from nodejs stdin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a simple program in Visual studio code terminal using node.js which requires reading inputs from the user and the operating on those inputs and printing the results.

I have tried many approaches but have not got success yet. I am using the following code:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
var input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", (c) => (input += c));

process.stdin.on("end", () => {
  console.log(input);
});

process.stdin.on("SIGINT", () => {
  console.log(input);
  const { EOL } = require("os");
  const lines = input.split(EOL); /*your input text, split by lines*/
  console.log(lines);
});
```

I run the above code in **VSCode** using the in-built terminal with the command `node filename.js`. The program runs and keeps taking inputs but it never ends and never triggers "end" block or "SIGINT" block. Finally to stop the program I have to use ctrl+C.

Can someone please help me how to accomplish this as I want to practise solving [www.codeforces.com](http://www.codeforces.com) problems on my local machine using VSCode+terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This way it won't quit until you explicitly end the program. You can use `process.exit()` function to achieve that.

So your program should look like this :

```js
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
var input = "";
const inputLength = (Math.random()*10 +1) | 0;
console.log(inputLength);
let current=0; 
process.stdin.on("data", (c) => {
  input += c;
  current++;
  if(current>= inputLength){
    console.clear();
    console.log("reached max number of inputs");
    console.log(input);   
    process.exit(0);
  }

});
```

Here is the [glitch](https://glitch.com/%7Erandom-number-of-inputs) link. You can test it opening console below and type `node server.js`

Comment: No, this does not work. I have entered 10 lines of data in terminal and still no results. According to your hack, the output will only print if current>= inputLength.

Comment: @user818455 made some minor fixes and it is working check out the glitch link.

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I don't understand what do you want to achieve, but you can write something like:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
})

rl.on('line', (input) => {
    console.log(`Received: ${input}`);
});
```

when you hit enter, you will see you line. CTRL+C also works

readline is a part of the standard library